# Java ScriptingManager access and use functions

Tags: java, javascript, scripting

I`m figuring out the Scripting support of Java, I  currently have this test class

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;



/**
 *
 * @author Makerimages
*/
public class main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, FileNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {

    // create a script engine manager
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    // create JavaScript engine
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    // evaluate JavaScript code from given file - specified by first argument
    engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("C:/Users/**/Documents/NetBeansProjects/test/src/l.js"));

}
public void makeObject(String s)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}

}
```

and this l.js file

```
makeObject("afzsdf");
```

when I try and run this I get

> run:
>   Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "makeObject" is not defined. (#1) in  at line number 1
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:224)
>       at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
>       at main.main(main.java:34)
>   Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "makeObject" is not defined. (#1)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3771)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3749)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3834)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.getNameFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2219)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1510)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:849)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:429)
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:116)
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(RhinoScriptEngine.java:109)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3161)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:173)
>       at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1159)
>       at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:214)
>       ... 2 more
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

How ca I fix it so I can use the makeObject function in the script???

Comment: have you read the documentation?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add bindings, e.g. link your Java objects to JS scope.

Java:

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, FileNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {

        // create a script engine manager
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        // create JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        //bind main instance
        Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
        bindings.put("main", new main());
        engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);

        // evaluate JavaScript code from given file - specified by first argument
        engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("l.js"));

    }

    public void makeObject(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

in JS you reference this `main` object:

```
main.makeObject("afzsdf");
```

Comment: Brialliant! works wonders! But, is there also a way I can evaluate an entire folder worth of .js files, and subfolders of that folder aswell?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think there is such method - you just iterate over the files in the right order and compile them. Feel free to ask this at SO if you have troubles.